# How to filter out data using dates

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter out dates based on the quarter inputed into the input box but it keeps throwing an error. I am a bit new to vba and still learning. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.
This is what I have come up with so far.

```
ResponseYr = SdrYear
ResponseQtr = SdrQtr

If ResponseQtr = 1 Then
BeginDate = "1 / 1 /" & ResponseYr & "0:00"
BeginDate = DateSerial(ResponseYr, 1, 1)
EndDate = "31 / 3 /" & ResponseYr & "0:00"
EndDate = DateSerial(ResponseYr, 3, 31)
'Quarter1 = Range("BeginDate:EndDate")


ElseIf ResponseQtr = 2 Then
BeginDate = "1 / 4 /" & ResponseYr & "0:00"
BeginDate = DateSerial(ResponseYr, 4, 1)
EndDate = "30 / 6 /" & ResponseYr & "0:00"
EndDate = DateSerial(ResponseYr, 6, 30)
'Quarter2 = Range("BeginDate:EndDate")

ElseIf ResponseQtr = 3 Then
BeginDate = "1 / 7 /" & ResponseYr & "0:00"
BeginDate = DateSerial(ResponseYr, 7, 1)
EndDate = "30 / 9 /" & ResponseYr & "0:00"
EndDate = DateSerial(ResponseYr, 9, 30)
'Quarter3 = Range("BeginDate:EndDate")

ElseIf ResponseQtr = 4 Then
BeginDate = "1/10/" & ResponseYr & "0:00"
BeginDate = DateSerial(ResponseYr, 10, 1)
EndDate = "31 / 12 /" & ResponseYr & "0:00"
EndDate = DateSerial(ResponseYr, 12, 31)
'Quarter4 = Range("BeginDate:EndDate")
End If
With ActiveSheet.Range("A:AD")
'.AutoFilterMode = False
.AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:=Array("Accept", "Alteration Change Commencement Date", "Alteration 
Reinstatement", "Alteration Manual", "Term Expire", "Claim Repudiated", "Claim Payment Done"), 
Operator:=xlFilterValues
.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=">=BeginDate", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=EndDate"
 End With
```

Comment: What line throws the error, and what is the error message?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question completely, it would be helpful to know where the error occurs. To filter for the desired date you have to separate the string and variable:

```
.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=">=" & BeginDate, Operator:=xlAnd,  Criteria2:="<=" & EndDate
```

But filtering for dates in excel vba can be tricky. You might also have to convert the date into a number:

```
 .AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=">=" & CDbl(CDate(BeginDate)), Operator:=xlAnd,  Criteria2:="<=" & CDbl(CDate(EndDate))
```

Comment: Good catch. Variables should not be within quotes, yes.

Comment: Assuming I input quarter 2, I get Type Mismatch error on this line of code                    
      BeginDate = "1 / 4 /" & ResponseYr & "0:00". The dates in the data have time attached to it. The time usually attached to it is 12:00:00 pm

Comment: Have you declared the variable ResponseYr? For Example: <Dim ResponseYr As String>. And how do you retrieve the content of the variable SdrYear?

Comment: Yes please, I declared it. I used the concept of an input box. Like this : Dim SdrYear As Integer
                Dim SdrQtr As Integer
                Dim ResponseYr As Integer
                Dim ResponseQtr As Integer                                                                         SdrYear = InputBox("Which Year?")
SdrQtr = InputBox("Which Quarter?")

Comment: ok, did you declare BeginDate and EndDate as Date? You have to use a whitespace between the ResponseYr and the time string: "1 / 4 /" & ResponseYr & " 0:00". Or if it is not necessary (and in this case it is not) just remove the timeString : "1/ 4 /" & ResponseYr

Comment: No please. I declared them as Long but will try that and give you feedback. Thanks

Comment: I declared them as Date but it is throwing a type mismatch error at the BeginDate of each quarter that is inputed in the input box, on this line :ElseIf                  
                ResponseQtr = 3 Then BeginDate = "1 / 7 /" & ResponseYr & "0:00"

Comment: You still have to use a whitespace at the start of the string after ResponseYr : 
`BeginDate = "1 / 7 /" & ResponseYr & " 0:00"`

Comment: Will try that. Thanks.